Finding eigenvalues of a matrix defined by a power series
If $A$ is an matrix defined by a power series $p(X)$, for $X \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, is it the case that all eigenvalues of $A$ are of the form $p(\lambda)$ for $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $X$?
For reference, this came up while I was working through "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction" by Brian C. Hall, Chapter 3, Exercise 2
Let X be a linear transformation on a finite-dimensional real or complex vector space. Show that
$ A = \frac{I - \exp(-X)}{X}$
is invertible iff none of the eigenvalues of X (over $\mathbb{C}$) is of the form $2\pi i n$ with n a non-zero integer.
The expression is defined in terms of a power series. It's obvious that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $X$, then $(1 - \exp(-\lambda))/\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A. More generally, if $X$ is diagonalizable, then so is $A$, and its eigenvalues are all of that form. However, I'm not sure how to prove the converse if $X$ is not diagonalizable.
I know that every $X \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the limit of a a sequence of diagonalizable matrices, but I don't know if that would help me here. If $\lambda$ is a limit of numbers of the form $(1 - \exp(-\lambda_n) / \lambda_n$, it's not itself necessarily of that form.

Yes. You can use Jordan normal form instead of diagonalizing, the point being that when you apply a power series to an upper triangular matrix it does the obvious thing to the diagonal and the diagonal still tells you what the eigenvalues are.
